# No database objects in Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ado.net-entity-data-model

When adding a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2015, there are no database objects shown in Entity Model Data Wizard. It happens for both "EF Designer from database" and "Code First from database".

[image: Entity Model Data Wizard]

I have the needed permissions to the database objects. When I use Visual Studio 2010, the database objects are there.

I've used "Repair Visual Studio" in Control Panel and re-installed Visual Studio 2015, still doesn't work.

The last thing I did before this issue occurred was running "Enable-Migrations" and "Add-Migration Initial" in Package Manager console as instructed here: [Web API Tutorial](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)

Comment: Are you sure that you have tables in this Database? it seems like this Database is empty

Comment: Yes there are tables in the database. I've used different databases, they still do not show up in the wizard. When I use Visual Studio 2010, the tables and other database objects are there.